# Trying to show that equation has a single solution using Banach space Theorems

Tags: banach-spaces, integral-equations

How do I show that
$f(x) = \int_0^1 e^{-sx}\cos(\alpha f(s))~ds, $   $0\leq x\leq1$,  $0\le\alpha\le1$
has a single solution.
Using Banach space Theorems like Contraction mapping theorem?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Let $T\colon C^0([0,1])\to C^0([0,1])$.
$$
 T(f)(x) = \int_0^1 e^{-sx} \cos(\alpha f(s))\, ds.
$$
We have
$$
\lvert T(f_1)(x)-T(f_2)(x)\rvert \le \int_0^1 e^{-sx}\lvert\cos(\alpha f_1(s))-\cos(\alpha f_2(s))\rvert\, ds
$$
Notice that $\cos$ on $[0,1]$ is $L$ lipschitz with $L=\sin(1)$. So
$$
\dots \le L\alpha\int_0^1 e^{-sx}\lvert f_1(s)-f_2(s)\rvert\, ds
\le L\alpha\lVert f_1-f_2\rVert.
$$ 
Hence $T$ is $L$ lipschitz with $L<1$ hence it is a contraction on a Banach space.